# way to override borders when border-radius not supported

Tags: internet-explorer, css, graceful-degradation

I am wondering if there is a way to not show borders when border radius is not supported without having to specifically target certain browsers/use modernizer. (I have a background image that shows up when no gradient support is present which includes the gradients&the rounded borders, but of course the gradient is showing around it).

```
li.toplevel {
font-size: 17px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 12px 18px;
height: 100px;
background: #eeeeee url('../images/headWig.gif') repeat-x; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%, #dddddd 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#eeeeee), color-stop(100%,#dddddd)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%,#dddddd 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%,#dddddd 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%,#dddddd 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%,#dddddd 100%); /* W3C */
border: 1px solid #BBB;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
border-radius: 8px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Best solution would be to use javaScript to detect if it's supported and then to execute whatever under what ever conditions.

Seems like you're looking for a non-javascript approach, (In general) you only need to worry about IE8 and below, and for that just use conditional CSS.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
CSS to Override borders etc
<![endif]-->
```